# GRUB packages removed during installation?

Tags: grub, package-management

I'm not sure exactly why these packages were removed, unless for an upgrade. But this current installation of elementary OS that I'm running was finally installed after 2 failed attempts where grub wouldn't install to `/dev/sda` (I finally went to the live desktop on the USB and installed from the desktop).

So, I'm not sure if I should be worried about this, because the computer is running fine, but it's just more out of curiosity as to why these packages were removed during installation. I was also connected to the Internet at the time to update packages.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you running with UEFI